# Is it correct to say “ I have been working out lately”?

Tags: adverbs, word-order

I want to know if is correct to say:

> I have been working out my body lately.

If the answer is yes, I want to know can I put the adverb “lately” at the beginning of the sentence or remove it directly ?

Comment: The phrase "working out my body" sounds strange - "my body" can definitely go, as in the subject line.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase in your question title (*I have been working out lately*) is correct. The one in the question body, though, is not: "working out" in the sense of "exercising" is an intransitive verb, you can't say "working out my body".

But yes, you can put the adverb at the beginning or the end (although when it's at the beginning you would probably use a comma):

> Lately, I have been working out.
>
> I have been working out lately.